# How to format a decimal that hasn't been initialized in C# MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, formatting, decimal

I'm building a form that displays currency amounts in a field. From the view, if the decimal hasn't been set, I'd like it to display "0.00"

How can I do this?

**View Model:**

```
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}")] //what I tried
public decimal MyDecimal { get; set; }
```

**View:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyDecimal)
```

The box shows "0" not "0.00"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DataFormatString = "{0:0.00}")` is only respected when you use `@Html.EditorFor()` or `@Html.DisplayFor()`

If using `TextBoxFor()` you need to use

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MyDecimal, "{0:0.00}")
```